# I accidentally broke my materials chest, what can I do?

Tags: rune-factory-4

Just got this game.

I accidently selected "break it" when inspecting the materials chest, thinking I could get my lumber and stone from inside.

Turns out, instead of re-appearing when exiting the screen and coming back, it's gone.

I can't seem to find another store that carries it. The general store, weapons, medicine, and food don't seem to have any "chests" of these kind.

Where can I get another one? Is my best hope restarting all over again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can buy one from **blossom** when you get the feature, it will cost you some gold and a few materials.

If you are just begining the game I think is best to restart and learn of your mistakes

Comment: I didn't understood why the down-vote ... so, +1

Answer (score 2):

my wife played for hours and found out that, just save the game. exit, re-enter the game. the box reappeared on the farm. I am not sure if it will work for you. but instead of restart, try save your game (on new save, in case you does not want to rewrite your previous save), exit the game (to 3ds home screen), then select the game again. good luck.